# SSRS - Report Builder: Show Items from groups in a column chart using tooltip

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder, ssrs-2016

I think that it might be easy, but I cant figure out how to make it work.

I have a column chart with tickets grouped by time (rounded to 15 minutes)

- X Axis - Time Group (Rounded to 15 minutes)
- Y Axis - Count(Tickets)

I'd like to show "ticket number" and "title" of all grouped tickets in one column as a **tooltip**

I have already tried lookup / lookupset / miltiplelookup - it didn't work. I have also tried to join the filed -> `=Join(Fields!IB.Value, ", ")`. That didn't work either. Im just getting `#error` by hovering over my column. If i'm just displaying the field, i'm getting only one value `=Fields!IB.Value`.

Any thoughts?

p.s. im Using Report-Builder and Ssrs2016

This how it may look like:

[image]

As i mentioned earlier, I have used some rounding function to group Tickets by the **time** Column. This is the code:

```
=Mid(Fields!time.Value,1,3) & Replace( Mid(Fields!time.Value,4,5),

Mid(Fields!time.Value,4,5),
    Switch(

Cint(Mid(Fields!time.Value,4,5)) >= 00 And Cint(Mid(Fields!time.Value,4,5)) <= 14, "00" ,

Cint(Mid(Fields!time.Value,4,5)) >= 15 And Cint(Mid(Fields!time.Value,4,5)) <= 29, "15" , 
   
Cint(Mid(Fields!time.Value,4,5)) >= 30 And Cint(Mid(Fields!time.Value,4,5)) <= 44, "30" ,
    
Cint(Mid(Fields!time.Value,4,5)) >= 45 And Cint(Mid(Fields!time.Value,4,5)) <= 59, "45" ))
```

Comment: I believe the solution involves LookupSet wrapped in a Join .... I recall doing something like this in the past, but it's been a while.  LookupSet should return the type of object that can be "join"-ed.  Obviously, a reference to the grouped / aggregated fields cannot be a direct parameter of Join() because it's not the right object type.

Comment: @Craig  I dont rlly understand, how can I make a reference to a grouped data? E.g.: I'm using `=lookupset(1, 1, Fields!Title.Value, "DataSet1")` -> it's getting me all the data in the chart (but I need only the data which was used to generate this particular column)

Answer (score 1):

As you probably guessed, your lookupset() will not work as it's compares `1` to `1` and therefore returns all values.

Assuming your time group column is called `TimeGroup` and your ticket number and title columns are called 'TicketID' and 'TicketTitle' then..

You need to change the lookupset to something like

```
=JOIN(
    LOOKUPSET(
        Fields!TimeGroup.Value,
        Fields!TimeGroup.Value,
        CSTR(Fields!TicketID.Value) & ": " & Fields!TicketTitle.Value,
        "DataSet1"),
        "," + vbcrlf
    )
```

Time group will always be evaluated in the context of the tooltip, so if you hover over time group `A`, time group will be evaluated as `A` and therefore the lookupset will only return values matching `A`.

The return part of the expression converts the ticket number to a string, adds a colon and then appends the title.

We wrap the whole thing in a JOIN() to combine the results of the LOOKUPSET array into a single string using `,` and `carriage return /line feed` between each instance so that the resultS show 1 per line.

Comment: That's the problem that I have. I dont't really understand what values should I use in the first 2 parameters. As I understood it; `lookupset` loops through all values and tries to find matches in it (1st parameter is my array, 2nd is the array in dataset, 3rd one will be shown, if there is a match). In my chart I have chosen `count(TicketID)` as a Y-Axis Value Therefore Ticket-IDs are to be matched, right? In your answer you have used TimeGroup, but there is no such column, I have just rounded TimeCreated Column to 15 minutes and groupt IDs by it

Comment: Just edited my question to show my grouping algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem with the function from [**@Alan Schofield**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66763096/10571625) using TimeGroup, but for that I hade to redefine my group settings:

1. Add custom field to my DataSet with the group function I mentioned in my question
2. Group my ColumnChart by this field
3. Use `count(Fields!TimeGroup.Value)` for the Y-Axis (instead of `count(Fields!TicketID.Value)`)
4. Join the Group from the Chart with the Group in DataSet and listing all results in the **tooltip**

**P.S. I hate this solution, but it works well**